# How often am I given a Test review question

Tags: discussion

At times, when I'm reviewing on AskUbuntu, I'm asked to review a Test question. E.g. user's question is completely messed up by a proposed edit, and when I click "Reject" it says "Congratulations, this was only a TEST ...".

I think I'm shown these Test questions too frequently. What governs the frequency of Test questions? Is it some behavior of mine? Can I adjust the frequency?

Comment: I think once every four reviews of that type.

Comment: According to moderators it is completely random - I remember getting two or more per day in every review category when I was doing more reviews than i am now.